# Como agrupar dados e listar noutra tabela em excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ola.

Eu tenho uma tabela de compras com varios registos e queria criar uma lista/tabela ao lado que contivesse o local de compra e a frente o valor total gasto nessa loja. segue abaixo um exemplo do que quero.

```html
<table><tr><th>NOME</th><th>VALOR</th></tr><tr><td>RP</td><td>192</td></tr><tr><td>RM</td><td>18</td></tr><tr><td>RP</td><td>92</td></tr></table>
```

Acima e a tabela com os varios dados a seguir vem a tabela que quero

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>NOME</th>
    <th>VALOR</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RM</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RP</td>
    <td>284</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**texto em negrito**

Como é que consigo isto no excel se possivel apenas com formulas sem macros.

Desde ja obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

## Tabela Dinâmica

É possível realizar isto com uma tabela dinâmica.

Em `Inserir` > `Tabela Dinâmica`, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Inserir Tabela Dinâmica]

## Resultado

[image: Resultado]

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Rótulos de Linha</th><th>Soma de VALOR</th></tr><tr><td>RM</td><td>18</td></tr><tr><td>RP</td><td>284</td></tr><tr><td>Total Geral</td><td>302</td></tr></tbody></table>
```